# Copiar y ordenar matriz en C

Tags: array, c

Estoy aprendiendo C pero aún soy muy novato. Me enfrento al siguiente problema: dada una matriz cuadrada debo copiarla en otra matriz y ordenarla de la siguiente manera:
Por ejemplo si trabajo con esta matriz de entrada:

```
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,1,2,1,1,0,0,0,0}
{1,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,0}
{2,2,1,0,2,1,0,0,0}
{1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

debo obtener la siguiente salida:

```
{1,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0}
{1,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0}
{2,2,1,2,1,0,0,0,0}
{1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

He intentado cambiando los indices de la matriz, "subiendo" las valores 4 posiciones hacia arriba pero no funciona. La solución debe servir para cualquier matriz cuadrada. Les dejo el código que he trabajado que me funciona para una matriz de 3x3 pero con esta de 9x9 no funciona. Espero me puedan ayudar para ver en que me equivoco.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int matriz[9][9]={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                  {0,1,2,1,1,0,0,0,0},
                  {1,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,0},
                  {2,2,1,0,2,1,0,0,0},
                  {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                };
int matriz2[9][9]={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                };
int m=0;
int n=0;
int i=0;
int j=0;
while(i<9){
    while(j<9){
        if (matriz[i][j]!=0)
        {
            while(matriz[i][j]!=0 && j < 9)
            {
                matriz2[m][n]=matriz[i][j];
                n++;
                j++;
            }
            if(j == 9)
                m++;
                n=0;
        }
        else
            j++;
    }
    i++;
    j=0;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
    {
        printf("[%d]",matriz2[i][j] );
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

este código me retorna:

```
{1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución a tu problema es:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int entrada[][9] = {
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,1,2,1,1,0,0,0,0},
  {1,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,0},
  {2,2,1,0,2,1,0,0,0},
  {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};

int salida[9][9] = { 0 };

int main( ) {
  int fila_salida = 0;

  for( int fila_entrada = 0; fila_entrada < 9; ++ fila_entrada ) {
    int col_salida = 0;
    int hay_datos = 0;
    for( int col_entrada = 0; col_entrada < 9; ++ col_entrada ) {
      if( entrada[fila_entrada][col_entrada] ) {
        hay_datos = 1;
        salida[fila_salida][col_salida] = entrada[fila_entrada][col_entrada];
        ++col_salida;
      } else if( hay_datos ) {
        ++col_salida;
      }
    }
    if( hay_datos ) ++ fila_salida;
  }

  for( fila_salida = 0; fila_salida < 9; ++fila_salida ) {
    for( int col_salida = 0; col_salida < 9; ++col_salida ) {
      printf( "%d ", salida[fila_salida][col_salida] );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Verás que hay muchos cambios con respecto a tu código:

- Variables con nombres comprensibles.
- Limitamos el ámbito de las variables al mínimo.
- Inicializamos la formación `salida` de forma mas simple, rellenándola con `0`.
- Usamos `for( )`, que nos ahora comparaciones posteriores y deja el código mas claro y limpio.

Comment: Me ha sido muy útil! muchas gracias por tu ayuda, solo tengo una duda: ¿Porqué la matriz entrada esta definida como constante?

Comment: Por costumbre. Siempre pongo `const` aquello que no debe ser modificado. Así, el compilador te avisa si te *equivocas* de variable :-)

Comment: Ya veo, nuevamente muchísimas gracias!